# How do I disable column sorting in JavaFX TableView

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview

I have noticed that sorting by column headers in the JavaFX TableView class is turned on by default.

In my case I need to have a table view that does not allow sorting by any of the columns. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 33):

If you created the table columns at own instances like this:

```
TableColumn<Type, Type> column = new TableColumn<>("email");
```

then you can easily set

```
column.setSortable(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use fxml, you can also set the column unsortable in fxml:

```
<TableColumn sortable="false"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Prevent a TableView from doing TableColumn sorting.
 *
 * @param _tableView
 * @param _actionPrevent  :set ON and OFF the 'Sortability' of columns.
 */
static
public < T > void preventColumnSorting( TableView< T > _tableView, boolean _actionPrevent )
{
    Platform.runLater( () ->
    {
        _tableView.getColumns()
            .forEach( column_ ->
            {
                column_.setSortable( ! _actionPrevent );
            } );
    } );

    return;
}
```